# MATLAB: What is the simplest way to get an element of an matrix multiplication?

Tags: matlab

What is the simplest way to get an element of an matrix multiplication?

Assume $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matricies. And $1\le i\le n$ and $1\le j\le n$ are inidicies

I tried $(A*B)(i,j)$ but this is no valid MATLAB syntax.

Sure an other way is $C=A*B$ and then $C(i,j)$ but this to complex and long for me.

Is there a trick to do that in a simple and compact way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ real matrices with $A=(a_{i,j})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ and $B = (b_{i,j})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$, for a given $(i,j) \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,n \rbrace^{2}$,

$$ \big( AB \big)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{i,k}b_{k,j} $$

As a consequence, you could try : `dot(A(i,:)',B(:,j))` in `MATLAB`.

Comment: And of course the vector dot product with `dot` is equivalent to `A(i,:)'*B(:,j)`.

Comment: Careful with that `'`. It should be `.'`. The distinction matters if the matrix is complex

Comment: @LuisMendo : Thank you for your comment. I didn't know that !

Comment: @jibounet Many people don't, and then they get problems due to the unexpected complex-conjugate :-)